# Image not showing on IIS when MVC app is hosted on IIS..works on ASP.NET Devlopment server just fine

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a view which looks like this
{{img src="/Scenario/Status/id" alt="status" /}}

(replace <> these {} above )

and this is the code in action of the controller

```
    public ActionResult Status(int? id)
    {
        // Calculate the status
        int no = new Random().Next(0, 2);
        string file = "green.jpg";
        if (no == 0)
        {
            file = "red.jpg";
        }
        else if (no == 1)
        {
            file = "yellow.jpg";
        }
        else if (no == 2)
        {
            file = "green.jpg";
        }
        var path = Server.MapPath("/Content/images/");
        var filePath = path + file;

        return new FileContentResult(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath), "image/jpeg");
    }
```

This works just fine when i run on visualstudio. But when i deploy it to local IIS, I dont see these images.
I checked that the "StaticContent" option is checked in Windows Features under IIS and also that the MIME type is enabled on IIS. I also checked that the *.jpg files are present under "inetpub" folder of my app after I publish from visual studio. Since i'm using virtual path for images and not hardcofing the filenames , it should work...

I just tried this

{{img src="../Content/Images/Green.jpg" alt="status" /}} and that works too.. :(

What else could be wrong?

Comment: When you deploy to IIS are you deploying to a virtual directory or the site root?

Answer (score 2):

A quick way to gain more insight into the problem would be to set a breakpoint in the `Application_Error` method of the global.asax, and see what exception is being raised when the request for the image comes in.

If you've deployed under a virtual directory in IIS, You'll need to use `Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/")`
Where Asp.Net will replace `~` with the application root.

Comment: that didnt work...and I dont see a method called Application_Error in my Global.asax.cs file

Comment: You can create it `protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e){}`.  Checking the Exception there `Server.GetLastError()` Should yield a useful exception.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution for displaying images in an app hosted in a sub folder unde root site on IIS

This worked..

img src = "<%= Url.Content("~/Home/GetRainfallChart") %>" alt="chart"

Comment: How can you do that if image from CSS style.

Answer (score 0):

It is deployed to a virtual directory C:\inetpub\wwwroot\testsite....
Is that th eproblrm